# okhttp not downloading the file

Tags: android, video, okhttp

I am using okhttp for downloading video from server. there is no error no exception but the file is not downloading every where but it seems as it is.

Here is the code:

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
Call call = httpClient.newCall(new Request.Builder().url("http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/video/upload/v1427018743/ygzxwxmflekucvqcrb8c.mp4").get().build());
 try {
        File file = new File(getCacheDir(), user_Videos.get(i).video_title+ ".mp4");
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        Response response = call.execute();
        if (response.code() == 200) {
           InputStream inputStream = null;
           try {
                inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
                byte[] buff = new byte[1024 * 8];
                long downloaded = 0;
                long target = response.body().contentLength();

                 publishProgress(0L, target);
                 while (true) {
                      int readed = inputStream.read(buff);
                       if (readed == -1) {
                           break;
                                        }
                          //write buff
                     downloaded += readed;

              try {
                   out.write(buff,0,readed);

                  } catch (Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                   publishProgress(downloaded, target);
                     if (isCancelled()) {
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    return downloaded == target;
                                } catch (IOException ignore) {
                                    return false;
                                } finally {
                                    if (inputStream != null) {
                                        out.flush();
                                        out.close();
                                        inputStream.close();
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return false;
                        }
```

The progress is showing correctly but video is not showing in directory.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you added the permission to write to the storage?

Comment: Yeah I did but no luck.

Comment: `video is not showing in directory.`. How do you look in that directory? And what is the full path of that directory?

Comment: `Have you added the permission to write to the storage`. There is no permission needed for that directory.

Comment: this is the file path :/data/data/com.rev.rev/cache/Gold -en.mp4 besides that I searched on other places too. with file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is no problem in my code but the path. Thanks @greenapps who made me think about path/ directory.

Basically I just change the path to a real one instead of cache and yup here is the video.

Changed this line

```
 File file = new File(getCacheDir(), user_Videos.get(i).video_title  + ".mp4");
```

to this

```
 File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), user_Videos.get(i).video_title+ ".mp4");
```

Thanks  @greenapps for the clue.

Comment: You shouldn't hardcode `"/sdcard"`. You should also consider removing WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission since it is a "dangerous" permission on Android 6.0+.

Comment: use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()` instead. Hardcoding `"/sdcard"` will work on the majority of devices but it is most likely a symlink and may not exist on some devices.

Comment: than what about those devices on which it doesn't work?

Comment: use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`